# Line up two elements with a `backdrop-filter: blur()`

Tags: css

When you line up two elements with a `backdrop-filter: blur()` you (naturally) get an ugly line down the middle. None the less two such elements next to each other might be desirable when you need more complex shapes than a simple square. How can two elements line up without creating such an ugly line?

> Warning: This only works in Chrome with experimental web platform features enabled, and possibly in Safari and Edge 17.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
.cover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#left {
  left: 0px;
  top: 10px;
}
#right {
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="left" class="cover"></div>
  <div id="right" class="cover"></div>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/google.jpg">
<div>
```

Comment: You want perfect rectangle instead of this?

Comment: It is not clear to me what your question is.

Comment: @AbhishekShah I attempted to clear up the ambiguous 'this' in the question. I want to prevent the 'blur line' in the middle of the image.

Comment: @ecg8 I have attempted to clear up the question more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already limited to webkit, may be you can take advantage of clip-path. Use a single cover element, and give it the shape that you want.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
}
.cover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 10%, 50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 50% 90%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 10%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/google.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Will need to take a good look at this (not sure I can animate `clip-path` in the way I need), but so far looking very good :D .

Comment: Happy that it helped. You can animate it as long as you keep the number of points constant. But you can always have 2 points at the same coordinates, if needed.

Comment: Sadly I am somehow trigger a weird webkit bug causing it to completely stop transitioning in my case (if I remove either the `backdrop-filter` or the `transition` it works, but both at once hide the element completely), but once they fix it it will at least be easy to add. Just a pity that Edge takes the same `-webkit-` prefix.

Comment: I have seen the bug, and tried to get a workaround without luck. May be you could switch to svg ?

Comment: And here I thought I was trying fairly cutting edge stuff  . Anyway, in my case I am going to leave it without the blur for the time being. It looks stunningly beautiful, but already now I have frame drops occasionally on my work laptop, with a functioning blur effect I fear my client's laptops would actually not be able to handle it. At the moment even considering switching to a canvas element, even if that means I won't get to use the blur ever  .

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the `clip-path` solution provided by @Vals you can use multiple gradient like this:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
}
.container:before {
  content:"";
  background:
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.1),rgba(0,0,0,.1))0 20px/50% 100% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.1),rgba(0,0,0,.1))100% -20px/50% 100% no-repeat;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 1;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/google.jpg">
<div>
```

Comment: What's the general idea here? Increasing the blurred area towards the edge so the effect overlaps?